# Face Detection (Face-API call) using Cordova Camera Plugin & MS-Cognitive Services in JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, meta-tags, azure-cognitive-services

Since last 2 days I am trying to figure out what went wrong? I am working on Cordova android app for Face recognition by using Microsoft Cognitive Services. For taking images I used Cordova Camera plugin and for performing operations (detect faces, identify etc) I am using JS. I will explain code step by step in this post.
Here is my Content Security Policies:

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="media-src * blob:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
 <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
 <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
 <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
```

After that standard HTML Code for display button of Capture Picture

```
<button id="take-picture-button">Take Picture</button>
```

Now lets come to .js file code, Since it is Cordova Camera plugin I used some pre-defined events:

```
    bindEvents: function () {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    document.addEventListener('pause', this.onPause, false);
    document.addEventListener('resume', this.onResume, false);
},
 onDeviceReady: function () {
    document.getElementById("take-picture-button").addEventListener("click", function () {
        appState.takingPicture = true; 
        navigator.camera.getPicture(cameraSuccessCallback, cameraFailureCallback,
            {
                sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                targetWidth: 500,
                targetHeight: 500
            });     });
},
```

and after that onPause: function(){} & onResume: function(){}
Following is the code where I am making an ajax call by using MS-Cognitive services Face API for face detection: (From the FaceAPI documentation I understood that I can either send Binary data or Blob or File in POST method, therefore I need to convert image into binary data) I am going to post the image conversion code and ajax code together so that you guys can understand.

```
  var img = new Image();
img.src = imageUri;  // System Path (eg: file:///storage/android/.......)

    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = $(window).width();
    canvas.height = $(window).height();

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    img.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    }
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

    var data = dataURL.split(',')[1];
    var mimeType = dataURL.split(';')[0].slice(5)
    var bytes = window.atob(data);
    var buf = new ArrayBuffer(bytes.length);
    var byteArr = new Uint8Array(buf);

    for (var i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        byteArr[i] = bytes.charCodeAt(i);
    }

var params = {
    "returnFaceId": "true",
    "returnFaceLandmarks": "false",
    "returnFaceAttributes": "age",
};

var faceIds = new Array();
$.ajax({
    url: "https://australiaeast.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect?" + $.param(params),
    beforeSend: function (xhrObj) {
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "API_KEY");
    },
    type: "POST",
    data: byteArr,
    processData: false,
})
    .done(function (data) {
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                faceIds.push(data.faceId);
                alert("FaceID at index"+ i+" is " + JSON.stringify(data.faceId[i]));
            }
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Failed in Face Detect, Details:  Status:: " + jqXHR.status + "  ResponseText:: " + jqXHR.statusText + "");
    });
```

Now, the output of above code is "Failed in Face Detect, Details: Status::400 ResponseText:: Bad Request
I am not understanding where I need to make changes or did I missing anything?
Please Help. 
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

There should be a message in the response to tell you what went wrong.There are several possible causes, like InvalidImage, InvalidImageSize etc. Please refer to the doc [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236) for the list of error code and message.